# CodeIgniter "csv_from_result" store in temp memory to be zipped

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, zip

I will create 3 CSV files 2 of which will be created using array data while the other one will be generated using CodeIgniters own function **csv_from_result** since it is a query result.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707620/php-create-multiple-csv-files-in-memory-then-compress) question I can take care of the 2 CSV from the array, But my problem here is the one from **csv_from_result** how will I modify it so that it can be included in the zip file.

```
            $rows = $this->my_pdo->get_records($start, $end);
            $new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($rows);
            force_download('detailed_report_'.$start.'-'.$end.'.csv',$new_report);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this (with huge tables csv_from_result give me errors)

```
$csv = fopen('php://temp', 'rw');
foreach($rows->result_array() as $row){
   fputcsv($csv,$row);
}
$file=stream_get_contents($csv, -1, 0);
fclose($csv);
```

Now in $file we have csv. For ZIP... (use codeingiter library https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html)

```
$this->load->library('zip');
$this->zip->add_data('detailed_report_'.$start.'-'.$end.'.csv', $file);
$this->zip->download('detailed_report_'.$start.'-'.$end.'.zip');
```

Comment: so this is an alternative to using `csv_from_result`. Thank you, I will give this a try