# PHP Zip Archive is Empty

Tags: php, file, csv, zip, php-ziparchive

I need a little help here.
I intended to create 2 csv files in PHP and have the browser download them.
This will happen when users click a button. However, I discovered that only 1 file download is permitted for each http request. I stumbled upon this stackoverflow post [PHP Create Multiple CSV Files in Memory then Compress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707620/php-create-multiple-csv-files-in-memory-then-compress/27708728). The solution creates 3 csv files in-memory and added them into a zip file and download it to the client's browser.

```
$headers = array('id', 'name', 'age', 'species');
$records = array(
    array('1', 'gise', '4', 'cat'),
    array('2', 'hek2mgl', '36', 'human')
);

// create your zip file
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// loop to create 3 csv files
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

    // create a temporary file
    $fd = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:1048576', 'w');
    if (false === $fd) {
        die('Failed to create temporary file');
    }

    // write the data to csv
    fputcsv($fd, $headers);
    foreach($records as $record) {
        fputcsv($fd, $record);
    }

    // return to the start of the stream
    rewind($fd);

    // add the in-memory file to the archive, giving a name
    $zip->addFromString('file-'.$i.'.csv', stream_get_contents($fd) );
    //close the file
    fclose($fd);
}
// close the archive
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);

// remove the zip archive
unlink($zipname);
```

I tried the solution marked as correct, but it didn't work.
A zip file was downloaded, but it is empty.

[image: var_dump($zip) shows that there are 3 files.]

Any help would be appreciated.

PS : Sorry, bad english, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: please provide the important/failing parts of your code.

Comment: I've edited the post by adding the codes.
Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. But i also had problems creating the zip-file because of permissions. You need to set right permission of the folder your script is running in and also of the script itself. Assuming you are under linux use `chmod` recursivly (`-R`):

```
chmod -R 666 your_folder
```

Comment: That's right !!!!!!!!
It really is an issue with permission.
This issue is now solved.
Thanks man.